# How can I build propane torch burners that have a custom configuration?

Tags: metalwork

For doing hard soldering I would like to have a propane burner with a custom configuration. The reason for this is that when soldering there is a region that ideally should be heated slowly, consistently and steadily up to the soldering temperature. Unless the area is small, this is usually not possible with a conventional torch head.

The most usual need is for a linear burner. So, for example, there might be an angle iron that is say 8" long that needs to be attached to a plate. So, in that situation I would want a burner that it is in a linear configuration about 8" long. Also, since the center of the region would get hotter faster, Ideally I would like to adjust the flame in the central orifices of the burner to be lower than the flames on the edges.

How can I build custom burners like this? Is it as simple as tapping an iron pipe and inserting orifices, or are there additional complexities? How do I find out more about the engineering of such burners?

Comment: A row of multiple nozzles sounds about right. If you need max temperature (as opposed to just heat), perhaps look at a welding torch for inspiration. At the simple end, look at the business end of a propane BBQ grill (pressure regulator and relatively wide metal tube with pinholes).

Comment: Commercial heat-treatment equipment supplier will likely will have or make a torch head.  Various shaped torches are routine for steel flame hardening. They mostly use oxyacetylene but could be modified for propane.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do this by watching videos posted by AndrewW on YouTube. [Andrew has done several different videos on fabricating propane burners of various kinds.](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCAn_HKnYFSombNl-Y-LjwyA) The essential elements of the burner are as follows in order from the tank:

- high pressure regulator (regulates gas flow from the tank to the burner)
- shutoff valve
- supply pipe with thread to accept orifice on one side
- venturi head -- the orifice screws into this on the other side
- burner manifold made of steel or cast iron with holes or slits in it where the flames come out

The videos make it clear how to connect and tune everything.

Comment: I havent watched the video, I'd be wary that the gas velocity at the nozzles is always high enough - so there should be something max. number of nozzles at size x in your considerations. AFAIK (and you mentioning a ventury seems to confirm this) these burners use a pre-mied flame, so there's a real danger of burnback into the manifold. Which would be bad.